# Google Places API does not return subpremise (Apt) if it is the first in the returned array

Tags: javascript, angular, api, google-places-api, google-places

If the address comes back like this "#301, 1833 N 105th St, Shoreline, WA 98133, USA", then the Apt number #301, is not taken as the subpremise. When the address is "1918 8th Ave #3200, Seattle WA, 89101, USA" The #3200 is taken as the Apt.

The entire address is being brought back with both cases, but Google does not recognize Apt numbers when they are the first value. I am working gin Angular and JavaScript so any advice within these technologies would be great.

```
for (i=0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
                        comp = place.address_components[i];
                        // State
                        if (!location.details.State && comp.types.indexOf('administrative_area_level_1') !== -1) {
                            location.details.State = comp.short_name;
                        }
                        // City
                        else if (!location.details.City && comp.types.indexOf('locality') !== -1) {
                            location.details.City = comp.long_name;
                        }
                        // Zip
                        else if (!location.details.Zip && comp.types.indexOf('postal_code') !== -1) {
                            location.details.Zip = comp.long_name;
                        }
                        // Street Name
                        else if (!location.details.Street.Name && comp.types.indexOf('route') !== -1) {
                            location.details.Street.Name = comp.long_name;
                        }
                        // Street Number
                        else if (!location.details.Street.Number && comp.types.indexOf('street_number') !== -1) {
                            location.details.Street.Number = comp.long_name;
                        }
                        // Apt
                        else if (!location.details.Apt && comp.types.indexOf('subpremise') !== -1) {
                            location.details.Apt = comp.long_name;
                        }
                    }
                    location.details.Street = (location.details.Street.Number + ' ' +location.details.Street.Name).trim();
                    if (!location.details.Street) {
                        location.details.Street = location.formatted_address_line1;
                    }
}
```